# Video not fitting inside container at all in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I am exhausted at this point. I have tried every possible solution available online and on stackOverflow to resolve this issue.

So basically I have a video that am tryingto fit inside a container but instead its sitting on container like as if being stacked onto it. I have tried using `FittedBox` to `ConstrainedBox` to `Chewie`but nothing working.

lt me show how it looks like:
[image]

and when the screen size is reduced:
[image]

My code:

```
    // ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

import 'components/constants.dart';

class Practice extends StatefulWidget {

  static const id = 'practice.dart';
  const Practice({super.key});

  @override
  State<Practice> createState() => _PracticeState();
}

class _PracticeState extends State<Practice> {

  late VideoPlayerController _videoMainController;
  late Future<void> _initializeMainVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //main video
    _videoMainController = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/vid6.mp4');
    _initializeMainVideoPlayerFuture = _videoMainController.initialize();
    _videoMainController.setLooping(true);
    _videoMainController.setVolume(0.0);
    _videoMainController.play();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoMainController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('V I D E O'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent[100],
      body: Container(
          width: 848,
          height: 480,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow, width: 4),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _videoMainController.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(_videoMainController))),
    );
  }
}
```

Adding complete code so its easier for you to try and test what can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the video player in a `ClipRRect` widget to add rounded corners to your video. To scale the video dynamically along with the screen width while keeping the aspect ratio, use the following width and height for your video container:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double containerMargin = 16.0; //space between edge of screen and video
    double aspectRatio = _videoMainController.value.aspectRatio;
    double dynamicWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - containerMargin * 2;
    double dynamicHeight = dynamicWidth / aspectRatio;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('V I D E O'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent[100],
      body: Container(
        width: dynamicWidth,
        height: dynamicHeight,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(containerMargin),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow, width: 4),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16), //20 minus yellow border width
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: aspectRatio,
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.cover, // Set BoxFit to cover the entire container
              child: SizedBox(
                width: _videoMainController.value.size.width,
                height: _videoMainController.value.size.height,
                child: VideoPlayer(_videoMainController),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently its solving the problem but new problem is, am using a Positioned in Stack widget and to that Positioned  is this ClipRRect becoming a child. How to avoid RenderAspectRatio unbounded constraints error?

Comment: Error: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderAspectRatio has unbounded constraints.

This RenderAspectRatio was given an aspect ratio of 1 but was given both unbounded width and unbounded height constraints. Because both constraints were unbounded, this render object doesn't know how much size to consume.

Comment: I then wrapped this whole ClipRRect with a sized box,now the renderAspectRatio issue is solved but video problem is back to what i shared in this question.Can you pls try an example and add video for reference

Comment: I have edited the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Ok this has solved every inch of the problem, a huge thanks to you for helping me solve a problem I was stuck into for a week.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using this container as a border. Should that be so, to keep it as a border, change your height and width to be dynamic to the size of your video because right now you have them set to constant values. Try something like this for the child of that container after you've adjusted the size constraints:

```
AspectRatio(
  aspectRatio: _videoMainController.value.aspectRatio,
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.cover, // Set BoxFit to cover the entire container
    child: SizedBox(
      width: _videoMainController.value.size.width,
      height: _videoMainController.value.size.height,
      child: VideoPlayer(_videoMainController),
    ),
  ),
)
```